# How to select only HTML and/or CSS code from any existing webpage's inspect element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand an html structure of a website but there is too much Javascript and other stuff. How can I selectively copy only HTML code and/or only CSS code from any existing webpage from the inspect element?

Went through all the existing questions-answers on stackoverflow but could not find anything that could let me separate the complete HTML and/or CSS code from a webpage.

Are there any tools which can help me with this? or there is any technique that I can use to select only HTML and/or CSS code from any existing webpage?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Chrome DevTools`  to see and manage the content of the web page.

---

Basically any `DevTools`, from any browser. Its must have for ***web developer***.

Comment: Or `Firefox Dev Tools`. Even `dev tools from Internet Explorer` can do this, even tough I personally can't recommend them.